# "Linux kernel source code directory" requested in Cisco VPN client install

Tags: software-installation, rpm, vpn, openbox, crunchbang

I'm trying to install Cisco's vpn client, and it requests that I provide the directory containing linux kernel source code. Specifically, it reads:

> In order to build the VPN kernel module, you must have the kernel
>   headers for the version of the kernel you are running.
>
> For RedHat 6.x users these files are installed in /usr/src/linux by
>   default For RedHat 7.x users these files are installed in
>   /usr/src/linux-2.4 by default For Suse 7.3 users these files are
>   installed in /usr/src/linux-2.4.10.SuSE by default
>
> Directory containing linux kernel source code []

where the last line is the prompt and the content in square brackets (in this case nothing) is the default directory.

I'm running crunchbang linux and I cannot find the directory containing the linux kernel source code. **Where is the directory containing the linux kernel source code?** Or, **how can I find it?**

Here's is what the manual, entitled *VPN Client User Guide for Linux and
Solaris* has to say about these kernel source requirements:

> To install the VPN Client, you must have the kernel source that was
>   used to build the kernel that is running on the system. If the system
>   is using a kernel that came as part of the Linux distribution, or a
>   custom built kernel, the kernel code can be obtained in different
>   ways:
>
> • For users running kernels that came with their distribution—You must
>   install the corresponding kernel-source rpm. The vpn_install script
>   should be able to automatically find the kernel source.
>
> • For users running a custom-built kernel—You must use the same copy
>   of the kernel source that was used to build the kernel you are
>   running. Unpacking the source code for the version of the kernel you
>   are using is insufficient. There are several files generated when the
>   kernel is compiled that the VPN Client uses. These files must exactly
>   match with the kernel you are running. Otherwise, the VPN Client
>   installation might fail.

Since I think I'm in the first case, I ran `sudo apt-get install rpm` (without knowing anything about rpm), and tried the installation again, hoping that the correct value would now be defaulted, but it wasn't and hence the installation still failed. **What is the "kernel-source rpm" and how do I install it?**

**EDIT**
As suggested, I tried to install `linux-headers-something`, but there were many auto-completions of `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` specifically, they were:

```
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-486
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-all
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-all-i386
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common-openvz
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common-vserver
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common-xen
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-openvz-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-vserver-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-xen-686
linux-headers-2.6.36-2.dmz.5-liquorix-686
linux-headers-2.6-486
linux-headers-2.6-686
linux-headers-2.6-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6-amd64
linux-headers-2.6-liquorix-686
linux-headers-2.6-openvz-686
linux-headers-2.6-vserver-686
linux-headers-2.6-vserver-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6-xen-686
```

**How can I determine which one I should install?**

Comment: You may need to install the kernel source as a separate package.  Try apt-get install linux-headers and apt-get source linux

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... CrunchBang Linux uses .debs, not .rpms. Try the `linux-headers-2.6-686` package or some variant thereof (e.g. `linux-headers-2.6-amd64` on a 64-bit installation). And you don't actually need the source code, you just need the externally-visible headers.

And beware 10-year-old instructions.

Comment: What is a "header"?

Comment: It's programmer-speak for "something C source files use". Frequently ends in ".h".

Comment: Does "Try the `linux-kernel-devel` package..." mean I should be able to `apt-get install linux-kernel-devel`? If so, it doesn't seem to be working. Of course, it might just be that I need to install a "variant thereof". In that case, any idea what a "variant thereof" might be called?

Comment: @Quinn In this context, the header files are generated when the kernel is compiled. They depend on the kernel version and configuration. You need header files that match your running kernel to compile additional modules. The package name is probably `linux-headers-something`. Install it with `apt-get install` or a package manager GUI.

Comment: @Gilles See my edit above regarding your suggestion.

Comment: @Quinn Install the one that matches your installed kernel. E.g. if you have the `linux-image-2.6-openvz-686` package installed (providing the file `/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.*-openvz-686`), then install `linux-headers-2.6-openvz-686`.